# Which OS should I install first?

Tags: system-installation

which system shall I install on a brand new computer? can I install ubuntu 14.04 first and wait a whilte with windows 8, undtil I get enoght money to buy it?

Comment: I'll say you should skip getting windows 8 as long as `wine` runs all your windows program.If you find a program that doesn't work on wine, try to find a alternative.If that too doesn't work, then think of getting some cheap windows OS.You would save a lot of money this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you **install ubuntu last**.

So, first you install windows 8 and then install ubuntu. Because when you install windows 8 after installing ubuntu, it will messed up linux GRUB (something like bootloader for ubuntu), and you will be in difficulty on going into your ubuntu OS.

But, when you're ready to handle this, it is not a problem. You can follow a guide from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) (that will led you download boot-repair-disk from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)).